# Postgres Behavior of Collisions with ORDER BY and Equals vs. IN

Tags: postgresql

I see the following anomaly in Postgres: I have a query as follows,

```
SELECT ... 
   FROM study_t s 
        INNER JOIN PUBLIC.study_participants_t sp
               ON ( s.id = sp.study_id )
        INNER JOIN PUBLIC.users_t u 
               ON ( sp.user_id = u.id )  
   ...
   WHERE s.id = 7493
   GROUP BY ...
   ORDER BY 
          u.user_name,
          r.created_date,
          activitystarttime
```

Even with the 3 columns in `ORDER BY` there are occasional collisions. **However, from run to run, the order of the remaining collisions always remains 100% the same.** No matter how many times I run this query the results are identical.

However, as soon as I introduced the `IN` keyword in `WHERE` as follows,

```
WHERE s.id in ( 7493, 7351 )
```

then I started getting differently-ordered collisions. The order of the remaining unordered collisions is no longer the same. I actually don't know if it's *consistently different* or *inconsistently different* from Query 1.

Is there anything that explains this behavior? Why wouldn't I ever get collision discrepancies in Query #1 with a single Equals value?

Comment: You cannot assume any sort order of rows that is not defined in the `ORDER BY` clause. In other words, if you expect a specific order of rows, you have to specify this order in the clause.

Comment: What do you mean by "collision"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running both queries with `EXPLAIN` prepended to the front and see if the execution plans are actually the same. I suspect they are not, which means the optimizer is taking a very slightly different approach to generating the two result sets (even though the final product is the same data), which would cause the differences.

I would call what you're seeing "predictable randomness." As @klin pointed out, this behavior is no guarantee. But at the same time, if the database is in roughly the same state each time the query runs, it's possible that it will happen to return results in the same order each time. It's not safe to assume the behavior, but it shows that the database isn't exactly going out of it's way to create disorder. The seemingly immaterial change that you're making must be causing some difference in the optimizer plan.

Comment: Even the same query may produce rows in a different order (when it is not defined), for example when a row has been modified in the meantime.

Comment: @klin agreed 100%, but in this instance it sounds like OP is getting "predictable randomness" for lack of a better term, and this would explain why 2 queries that produce the same result set don't have the same "randomness" behavior. Like an entropy source that often gives the same first `n` values at startup even though it is technically not deterministic.